# Azure Queue Trigger no longer works after switching to Azure StorageQueue

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-storage-queues

Recently upgraded from Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Queue to Azure.Storage.Queues.
After upgrading packages the Queue Trigger no longer picks up the stored queue.

Here's the code for sending messages:

```
public async Task SendMessage<T>(T payload)
{
   var message = new Message<T>
   {
      Payload = payload
   }

   var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message)
   await queue.SendMessageAsync(content) //queue is of type QueueClient
}
```

The Queue handler

```
[FunctionName("QueueHandler")]
public async Task QueueHandler([QueueTrigger("queuename")] string message)
{
   //Deserialize message
}
```

Please let me know if any more info is necessary

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into [Azure Storage queue trigger.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4625)

Comment: @RajeshM - look at their code snippet: they're using `[QueueTrigger()]` which is for Storage queues.

Comment: Check this Document if helps [Link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/storage/queues/storage-tutorial-queues.md)